# iOS uploading assets library images and photos to a server in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I'm having difficulty by uploading to a server from iOS assets library. Successfully I managed to get the photos datas and store them in an array, however I cannot managed to send them to the server in a best way.

I tried the NSOperationQueues, AFNetworking, NSSessionUploadTasks.. I'm aware of them however couldn't get the send them 1 by 1 in a queue to the server. Maybe I did not correctly implemented the functions.

If I tried to send them like

```
   NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

calling it in a thread it's going 1 by 1 however when the app is suspended my connection is failed and it stops sending the photos.

If I tried to send them like

```
-(void)sendImageUploadOperation:(NSData *)image setURL:(NSURL *)url{

NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:600];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:image]];

[urlRequest setHTTPBody:body];


NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.example.apple-samplecode.BackgroundSession"];

NSURLSession *upLoadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:urlRequest];

[uploadTask resume];
```

}

It says : "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Upload tasks in background sessions must be from a file " 
 even if I'm not sending the files url , i'm sending the NSData of the image that I processed before.

I'm stuck in the middle of the networking. Please somebody can help me how can I handle this situation. I'm tried to upload images on the foreground and continue in the background as well.And also I'm getting a response from the server if it is successfully added or not. So the response is very important for me and send all the images I selected 1 after another .

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLSession and stream upload in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974673/nsurlsession-and-stream-upload-in-background)